# How i can apply styles like .myClass li {

Tags: material-ui

I need to know how i can do to apply an heritage with material UI ?

For exemple if i need to apply a style to all **li** items in an **ul** which has the **.myClass** class.

Actually i don't know if there is a specific syntax in the style objects that i can use like the syntax for decorators ( hover etc ).

I tried things like that :

```
'.myClass li': {
   myStyle: blabla
}
```

PS: I'm using v1 of Material-ui

Thanks for help

Comment: Remove quotes and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found a solution using the same approach than for decorators :

```
myClass: {
    '& svg': {
        fontSize: '5em'
    }
}
```